# Why do react-native application close immediately?

Tags: react-native

*When i run react-native run-android, when bundle %100 application closes immediately. it says that "application is stopped".*

why this  happening ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nTiZ.png)

Comment: There can be multiple reasons.. maybe show the whole error log so we can help you out. Did you recently install a new package before it stopped working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @yesIamFaded there is no error, that is the problem. it works well but after run it says just app is stopped

Comment: yeah but there must be something.. is it a new app ? is it old? did u change some dependencies? did u upgrade expo cli or something? you have to tell us a bit more

Comment: it is old app. i didnt do anything on this project maybe 5 months. i just install it in new  phone via android studio and react-native run-android. it doesnt open. i didnt do  anything on project. What should i do ? @yesIamFaded

Comment: @yesIamFaded i added screenshot of error

Comment: Try `adb logcat -t <lines>` in your shell to find the actual reason why it crashes